# How to append multiple parent and child div in one single div using keypress jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a system in which main requirement is that user A press add more button and user will fill up data in it. Then add more again and more data.

What I really need to do is to embed 1st add more data and 2nd add more data in one div using keypress events.

For e.g,

1. user starting writing in 1st text field of 1st add more, then 2nd text field of 1st add more so it should embed this data in one div named: one
2. user starting writing in 1st text field of 2nd add more, then 2nd text field of 2nd add more so it should embed this data in one div named: two

At the end I want to embed both one and two divs in one single div.

Problem:

It does not including and embed the fields recursively in final div nor keypress is working as expected.

Als returning error `$(...).text(...).append is not a function`. That is coming in last line of code.

Jquery code:

```
children_container = $('<div/>', {'class': 'children_new_package_itineraries_container'});

if (children_container.length > 0) {

    $("#day_new_package_itineraries_field").on('keypress change', function () {
        $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'day_new_package_itineraries_container',
            'html': $(this).val()
        });
    });

    $("#title_new_package_itineraries_field").on('keypress change', function () {
        $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'title_new_package_itineraries_container',
            'html': $(this).val()
        });
    });

    children_container.append($(".day_new_package_itineraries_container").text().append($(".title_new_package_itineraries_container").val()));

    $(".preview_container").html(children_container);

}
```

Desired Output:

```
<div class="preview_container">

  <div class="children_1493016690115_container">
    <div class="day_1493016690115_container">Day: 123</div>
    <div class="title_1493016690115_container">Title: xyz</div>
  </div>

  <div class="children_1493016960131_container">
    <div class="day_1493016960131_container">Day: 123</div>
    <div class="title_1493016960131_container">Title: xyz</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

P.S: I am sitting `_1493016690115_` or `_1493016960131_` these values dynamically so that's not the issue how I am dealing these inputs dynamically.

Comment: You are only creating elements not `.append()`ing them

Comment: I have tried appending them but that does not work. Could you please fix it for me? :) I am unable to get the right results.

Comment: you need to appent it when you construct it in selector like this: `$( "<p id='test'>My <em>new</em> text</p>" ).appendTo( "body" );` - check jQuery [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

Comment: Tried but still does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can append where you are creating element

```js
children_container = $('<div/>', {'class': 'children_new_package_itineraries_container'});

if (children_container.length > 0) {

    $("#day_new_package_itineraries_field").on('keypress change', function () { 
      if($(".day_new_package_itineraries_container").length) {
        $(".day_new_package_itineraries_container").html($(this).val());
      }else{
       children_container.html($('<div/>', {
            'class': 'day_new_package_itineraries_container',
            'html': $(this).val()
        }));
     }
    });

    $("#title_new_package_itineraries_field").on('keypress change', function () {
      if($(".title_new_package_itineraries_container").length) {
        $(".title_new_package_itineraries_container").html($(this).val());
      }else{
       children_container.append($('<div/>', {
            'class': 'title_new_package_itineraries_container',
            'html': $(this).val()
        }));
}
    });

  
    $(".preview_container").html(children_container);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview_container"></div>
<input id= "day_new_package_itineraries_field">
<input id= "title_new_package_itineraries_field">
```

Comment: The drawback of using append with your way is, it does not remove existing text from the field. If user removes whole text or try adding more to existing text. It should take whole text as a value. I have tried that already :)

Comment: Then you should use .html instead of  using append

Comment: They are 2 different fields. Using html remove the 1st or 2nd filed data :) I have tried all these things already. :) Does not seems to work well.

Comment: Yes I have adjusted it wrt my requirements but still my problem is to make it working for multiple add more and embed just like my original problem :)